# Images on Mobile device need a browser refresh to become in focus

Tags: image, mobile

For some reason my images are only becoming in focus when my Safari browser refreshes when I am using my Iphone. I am not sure why this is happening.

IE, Chrome, Firefox seems to load the images fine on my desktop.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Zxndesignco.com

Comment: Also you will notice that the woocommerce images in the zoom window are nice and clear from the start.

Comment: Another point of reference. Sometimes when I switch from Portrait to Landscape or vice versa on my Iphone the images will also become out of focus after the switch.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments. A tip I just noticed.. Put your phone in landscape view and refresh the browser the image should become clear. Portrait takes multiple refreshing of the browser for the images to come into focus.